# show hide using Jquery for different id's

Tags: php, jquery

i have used the following code to show / hide div using javascript function.

how can i write this using Jquery ???
Id is different for each div.

**Javascript function:**

```
function showHide(id) {
    var divid = id;
    var ele = document.getElementById("showHideDiv_"+divid);
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
      }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

**Html and PhP code:**

```
for($i=1;$i<count($data);$i++) 
{
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return showHide(<?php echo $i; ?>);">

 <div id="showHideDiv_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="coomentbox" style="display:none;">
   // some content within div
 </div>

}
```

Comment: This is a **very** basic question. Requisite information is provided in the always-useful [jQuery API documentation.](http://api.jquery.com) I suggest you start there.

Comment: @MattBall:I know the show and hide method for Jquery but how to pass different id for click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function showHide(id) {
    var divid = id;

    if ( ( $( '#showHideDiv_'+id ).is( ":visible" ) ) 
              $( '#showHideDiv_'+id ).hide();
   else
               $( '#showHideDiv_'+id ).show();
}
```

Comment: :Thanks.I exactly want that.

Answer (score 1):

```
function showHide(id) {
   $( '#showHideDiv_'+id ).toggle();  
}
```